# python pandas: call pandas function on objects inherited from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I would like to inherit from pandas DataFrame, which does nothing except MyDF has fixed columns ('col1','col2','col3') and does not take any other column names.

```
class MyDF(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(MyDF, self).__init__(x)
        if not all(np.in1d(self.columns, ['col1','col2','col3'])):
            raise ...
...
```

Now I want to concatenate MyDF, but

```
mdfs = [mydf1, mydf2]
pandas.concat(mdfs, axis = 0)
```

gives

```
TypeError: 'BlockManager' object is not iterable.
```

I need to cast mydf to DataFrame, concat, then cast back

```
t = pandas.concat([DataFrame(i) for i in mdfs], axis = 0)    
out = MyDF(t)
```

Is this the right way to do it? I think this will create unnecessary copies of mydf in pandas_df

Also is it right to cast by calling SuperClassName(subclass_object)?

Thanks

Edit: Actually I found the issue is because somewhere inside pd.concat, it calls the class constructor (MyDF.__init__) with a BlockManager as its input. DataFrame.__init__ is happy to take the BlockManager and return a DataFrame, but MyDF.__init__ isn't. This causes the error message. I just added a line

```
if isinstance(data, (DataFrame, pd.core.internals.BlockManager) ):
    super(ODF, self).__init__(data)
```

and it now works

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  It seems to work for me on 0.14.1.

Comment: I don't think concat will ever return a MyDF though, so best to hope for will be `MyDF(pd.concat(mdfs))`.

Comment: Is that really all you do with MyDF? check for fixed columns? Just implement a method wrapping the DataFrame constructor and save yourself the headache. And regarding the cast - it's not casting. It's calling the constructor with MyDF as an argument. Casting is something else.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm on 0.14.1 as well, Python version is 2.7.7, Anaconda 2.0.1, Windows 64bit.

Comment: @Korem A few other changes as well, such as str and plot methods.

Comment: Can you show an actual code example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn please see the new edit.

Comment: You should probably define your `__init__` to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` and pass them on to the superclass.